# Not able to see network settings in Ubuntu 18.04 after upgrade

Tags: networking, 18.04, upgrade

**Back Story** : I have upgrade to 18.04 from 16.04, but operation didn't completed successfully, my dpkg was broken then somehow I restored it and I'm able to logged in after upgrade but even though I have plugged Ethernet cable, I'm not able to see anything connection icon in upper right corner so I have checked `ifconfig` command then I'm able to see my network adapter.

After that I have manually configured my IP address, default gatewat etc and somehow my network started working but connection is not stable..

**Summary of my problems**

1. Not able to see Network option to do changes using UI
2. Network connection is not at all stable

[image]

++++++++++++++++++++++ UPDATE +++++++++++++++++++++++++

## interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

My /etc/network/interfaces :

```
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
address 192.168.151.129
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcst 192.168.0.1
gateway 192.168.151.20
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: What do you mean by unstable? Does it lost IP address? Or packet lost? Also, check your interface isn't listed into /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

Comment: @olivierb2: by unstable means I'm losing internet connectivity ( packet lost ) and for interface please check my update..

Comment: So you should remove enp3s0 information (the content you pasted) if you want to see this interface in Network Manager.

Comment: @olivierb2: Thanks, after removing my code from "interfaces" file, it worked for me :)

Comment: Happy this helped you :D

Comment: @olivierb2: sorry this is another issue but after upgrade, I'm not able to boot normally, always I need to go in bios and select my boot option everytime, I tried to re-arrange boot sequence but its not working..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88792/discussion-between-pankaj-and-olivierb2).